# Firmware update of Surface Dock 1 reports error

Tags: updates, firmware, microsoft-surface, microsoft

I have updated a Surface Dock 1 with latest firmware (Version 1.53.139.0). Component10FirmwareFwVersion is set to the right version 4ac3970. But Component20CurrentFwVersion is not updated to 4a1d570.
Checking the log file shows Error 2006 (Failed to send offer/payload pairs). Update procedure has been tried a lot of times. All workarounds given in "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/surface-dock-firmware-update" have been done.
Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.